# How to import .C3D files into Blender?

Tags: animation, import, blender, file-type, motion

I'm trying to import Motion Capture files of extension `.C3D` . I found that Blender only supports `.bvh` files for Motion Capture Data. Is there a way to import C3D files into Blender?

Or a way to convert `*.c3d` to `*.bvh` ?

### What Have I Tried :

I found that there is a Blender add-on for importing C3D : located in [here](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Extensions:2.6/Py/Scripts/Import-Export/C3D_Importer).

but the file it is referencing apparently does not exist : 
http://projects.blender.org/tracker/download.php/153/467/29061/18217/io_import_c3d.zip

Maybe anyone has this file and be nice to upload it somewhere? If I can find the file, I promise I will report a bug and deliver the file link to them :)

Thanks for any help !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Blender includes a large list of import-export options. By default a lot of these aren't enabled, import-c3d  being one of them. I count 33 import-export addons in the current version with another 17 available that aren't normally included with an official release. Only 9 of these are enabled by default.

To enable an import addon you need to turn it on in the preferences - File->User Preferences under addons.

[image]

Click the Import-Export button (1) to list all import addons or enter a search term (2) to find by name. Then enable the addon by clicking (3) this will make the option available under File->Import.

As for the download link - projects.blender.org has just recently been replaced with develop.blender.org from the move from svn to git. Links in the wiki still need to be updated.

Comment: It works on Mac 10.10 Yosemite using Blender 2.72b:-)